# C++ for Ruby scripters

Tags: c++, ruby

I am a fairly capable Ruby scripter/programmer, but have been feeling pressure to branch out into C++. I haven't been able to find any sites along the lines of "C++ for Ruby Programmers". [This site](http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/python2Cpp.html) exists for Python (which is quite similar, I know). Does anyone know of a guide that can help me translate my Ruby 'thoughts' into C++?

Comment: In honesty, I don't recommend trying to apply your known language to a new language. They are two different languages, and you should attempt to learn C++ as it is, the C++ way. Trying to force C++ to be a language it's not, even if only for learning, will just a block. Get a good book and start from the beginning. If some parts happen to overlap Ruby, great!; you'll just breeze through that part a bit faster. But don't try to apply Ruby to everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that language introductions written specifically for migrants from a certain language have considerable advantage over traditional "independent" introductory books. Reading as a cognitive process has a great feature: *reading speed varies greatly*. That means that you should take any good C++ book (I'm sure you'll find excellent recommendations here on SO) and your reading speed will be greatly affected by your previous programming knowledge - reading about things you already know will become almost skimming-fast, others will take some time. In the end, you will spend practically the same amount of time as you would if you read a specific migrant course, with the difference of having read a book that you will be able to use as a language reference at any given time in the future, unlike the "transitional guide", which is always kind of "one-time read".

On the other hand, from a perspective of a writer, it's pretty ungrateful to assume (and rely on) such thing as reader's knowledge on a topic. When one says he knows Ruby is it really a guarantee that he knows OOP thoroughly, for example? Or just have been using it not understanding the internals (which is really easy for a Rails programmer, for example).

So a general book is a safe bet both for a writer and a reader. :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others. Your skills in Ruby will certainly help you to learn C++ in a way, but they are quite different. A great online book to learn C++ : [Thinking in c++](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)

Bruce Eckel's books are a really good start with an adapted learning curve. Simple to begin but going quite deep into the language. Recommended.

```
my2c
```

Comment: I wanted to do a project in C++, and by chance I found a copy of Thinking in C++. This is really one of the best books on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn C++, start [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840).
Once you have learned the fundamentals, you should also look into these:
[Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), 
[More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X), 
[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629), and
[Exceptional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615622)